# J'imagine que + subjonctif/indicatif

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, indicatif

Je suis tombé sur cet exercice où je dois répondre en utilisant un subjonctif ou un indicatif. Mais je ne suis pas sûr de quel mode je dois utiliser dans la phrase ci-dessous:

> Il est possible qu'il y **« ait »** une grève demain et j'imagine qu'il y **« aura/ait »** des embouteillages.

Selon mon livre, après la structure « Il est possible que/qu'il », il faut que l'on utilise le subjonctif, mais après la structure « s'imaginer que / imaginer que » cela dépend de certaines choses. Comme vu [ici](http://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic823-simaginer-que-imaginer-que-indicatif-ou-subjonctif.html), on pourrait utiliser le subjonctif ou l’indicatif selon la signification: si l'on veut exprimer un fait réel/probable ou une incertitude. Mais dans ce cas, la deuxième phrase dépend de la première, dans laquelle on a déjà utilisé le subjonctif ( donc, c'est irréel ), mais je pense qu'il y aura des embouteillages ( c'est presque certain ) dans le cas où la grève ait lieu. Sinon, il n'y aura pas d'embouteillages. Si je met le subjonctif, j'ai l'impression que ça ne marche pas, pourriez-vous me donner une explication concise?

Comment: J'ai édité votre question en corrigeant les fautes de français. N’hésitez pas à demander si vous ne comprenez pas une formulation :)

Comment: @Random Merci! J’apprécie toujours les corrections et il y avait des fautes imperdonables! Mais la seul que je ne comprends pas exactement pour quoi est "pense" au lieu de "penserais". C'est une situation qui se produira peut-être, n'est-elle pas? Alors, dans le cas où la grève ait lieu, je penserais qu'il y aura des embouteillages?

Comment: L'idée c'est que "penser" est une action présente. On peut reformuler en disant : « Aujourd'hui, je **pense** que l’événement de demain **entrainera** des bouchons à condition que la grève **ait** lieu ». Il y a dans cette phrase 3 verbes. Le fait de dire que quand il y a grève, il y a des embouteillages n'est pas conditionnel, c'est un résultat logique que vous pensez aujourd'hui, donc "Penser" est au présent. "Aura" est au futur car c'est un fait certain du futur, s'il y a des embouteillages. "ait" est au subjonctif, car suit "à condition que", c'est la seule chose incertaine de la phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'indicatif convient si on veut marquer une plus grande certitude, et en particulier, parce que **l'action se déroule dans le futur**.

> Il est possible qu'il y **ait** une grève demain et (si c'est le cas /
>   dans ce cas) j'imagine qu'il y **aura** des embouteillages.

Si l'ensemble est très hypothétique (même la seconde partie), on peut garder, subjonctif => conditionnel, mais elle est moins naturelle dans ce cas (les embouteillages sont presque assurés avec la grève).

> Il est possible qu'il y **ait** une grève demain et (si c'était le cas)
>   j'imagine qu'il y **aurait** des embouteillages.